# Multiple condition check in $match in mongoose aggregation

Tags: mongoose

can i do it like that?this is my query.

```
const result = await transactionDbSchema.aggregate([
{
$unwind: "$transactions"
},
{
$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$transactions" }
},
{ $match: { from: req.params.address,to: 
req.params.address} }
]);
```

i have to key in the db with the name "from" and "to" and i receive address "req.params.address" which may be in "from" or "to" key in the db. i want to search all object which has the address "req.params.address".i try  to do it in this way but it give empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put multiple conditions in `$match`, it is taken as `$and` by default, it will try to match all the given conditions, and return only those documents where all condition satisfies.

But from your question it looks like you need to find all the docs where the address is either in `from` or in `to` field.

you can use `$or` for this purpose.

**Try this:**

```
const result = await transactionDbSchema.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: "$transactions"
},
{
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$transactions" }
},
{   
    $match: { 
        $or : [{ from: req.params.address } ,
               { to:req.params.address}]
    }
}
]);
```

Read more about [MongoDb $or operator here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/).